# Question about class complex in the page 61 of book c++ programming language

Tags: c++

```
class complex {
double re, im; // representation: two doubles
public:
complex(double r, double i) :re{r}, im{i} {} // construct complex from two scalars
complex(double r) :re{r}, im{0} {} // construct complex from one scalar
complex() :re{0}, im{0} {} // default complex: {0,0}
double real() const { return re; }
void real(double d) { re=d; }
double imag() const { return im; }
void imag(double d) { im=d; }
complex& operator+=(complex z) { re+=z.re , im+=z.im; return ∗this; } // add to re and im
// and return the result
complex& operator−=(complex z) { re−=z.re , im−=z.im; return ∗this; }
complex& operator∗=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
complex& operator/=(complex); // defined out-of-class somewhere
};
```

In my opinion, the format of function declaration should look like that,  (return type) name (argument){}. In this case,

```
complex& operator+=(complex z) { re+=z.re , im+=z.im; return ∗this; }
```

The complex& is the return type and operation+ is the function name, but why it is followed by a "="?

Comment: `operator+` is **not** the function-name. This class is overriding the `+=` operator, not the `+` operator. Overriding `+=` instead of `+` means an extra value copy can be eliminated - though this doesn't seem right to me, I'd have thought the compiler would take care of that for you. Exactly what version of C++ are you using? If this is production code you should be using Boost's complex type rather than rolling your own...

Comment: It is not operator `+`. It is operator `+=` overloading.

Comment: @Dai If so, what does it mean by ```complex& operator+=(complex z) { re+=z.re , im+=z.im; return ∗this; }```

Comment: @oo I think MiniMik's answer explains the situation quite well.

Answer (score 1):

With `operator +` you can do something like:

```
c = a + b;
```

whti `operator +=` is used to add some data and store it in the first summand:

```
a += b;
```

Answer (score 0):

`operator+=` is itself a function.
The following expression

```cpp
com_num+=com_other;
```

is equivalent to the call.

```cpp
com_num.operator+=(com_other);
```